# How can I convert Java List Object to Json with this format? (see body)

Tags: java, json, list, pojo

anyone know how can I convert this Java List Object to Json?

```
List<SampleObject> sample = new ArrayList<SampleObject>();
```

to this format (notice that the Json is not an array)

```
{
  "0": {
    "firstName": "",
    "lastName": "",
  },
  "1": {
    "firstName": "",
    "lastName": "",
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance. Hope you can help me :)

Answer (score 0):

Convert your List to Map, where your key would be an Integer representing 0-based index in your list. After that convert your map to JSON by any standard way and you will get your format. To see how to serialize your Map (or any class) to JSON see this question: [How to serialise a POJO to be sent over a Java RSocket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68159772/how-to-serialise-a-pojo-to-be-sent-over-a-java-rsocket/68160307#68160307)